# nothing to do when use zf configure db-adapter

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm learning Zend Framework.

When I enter this line on command prompt:

```
zf configure db-adapter
```

I got :

```
Nothing to do!
```

Do I wrong? I'm reading this page:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they wrapped the command into multiple lines and made it a bit hard to tell.

The full command for the quick start without line wrapping is:

```
zf configure db-adapter 'adapter=PDO_SQLITE&dbname=APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/db/guestbook.db"' production
```

As shown on the quick start:

```
% zf configure db-adapter \
> 'adapter=PDO_SQLITE&dbname=APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/db/guestbook.db"' \
> production
```

The `\` character tells the shell to expect more input for the command after the carriage-return and not to attempt to process it yet.  The `>` is just them showing that their shell was waiting for more input for the current command.

You would have to copy what they put and remove the `>` in order to get it to run correctly, or copy the one line version above.